# Where does the NS lookup chain stop?

Tags: nameserver, domain-name

When does the NS lookup chain stop?

For example, if I go to `A.com` and the NS for `A.com` is `ns.B.com`.

Then the client (browser) needs to find out the IP for `B.com`, NS for `B.com` is `ns.C.com`.

Then the client needs to find out the IP for `C.com`, NS for `C.com` is `ns.D.com`.

Then the client needs to find out the IP for `D.com`, NS for `D.com` is `ns.E.com`..

I mean where does this chain stop exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking the NS records are stored as glue. So when you go to `a.com` you go to the root (*.root-servers.net) which are hardcoded into your dns servers.  In the case of .com you then get pointed at *.gtld-servers.net  which host the .com tld.  From there you would be given the NS records for `a.com` along with the IP addresses due to the glue records.   Here is an example of looking for google..

```
  [~] dig +trace google.com 

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> +trace google.com
;; global options: +cmd
.           321319  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           321319  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           321319  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           321319  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           321319  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           321319  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           321319  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           321319  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           321319  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           321319  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           321319  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           321319  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           321319  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
;; Received 512 bytes from 10.10.0.1#53(10.10.0.1) in 7 ms

com.            172800  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
;; Received 488 bytes from 192.5.5.241#53(f.root-servers.net) in 35 ms

google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns4.google.com.
;; Received 164 bytes from 192.26.92.30#53(c.gtld-servers.net) in 40 ms

google.com.     300 IN  A   72.14.204.105
google.com.     300 IN  A   72.14.204.103
google.com.     300 IN  A   72.14.204.99
google.com.     300 IN  A   72.14.204.147
google.com.     300 IN  A   72.14.204.104
;; Received 108 bytes from 216.239.36.10#53(ns3.google.com) in 124 ms
```

The address of ns3.google.com was obtained from the gtld-server  returned in the additional  section.

```
[~] dig @c.gtld-servers.net ns3.google.com       

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> @c.gtld-servers.net ns3.google.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62420
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 4
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns3.google.com.            IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns4.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns2.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.34.10
ns1.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.32.10
ns3.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.38.10

;; Query time: 44 msec
;; SERVER: 192.26.92.30#53(192.26.92.30)
;; WHEN: Sat Sep 24 10:04:56 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 164
```